# ROC and AUC for clustering algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, roc, auc, dbscan

I am working on some clustering algorithms like DBSCAN and local outlier factor. Now i want to know how can I make ROC and AUC curves from clustering results. Do anyone know how can i make RO and AUC curves. Thank You

Comment: in which programming language

Comment: I am using python

Comment: What would a ROC curve mean in this context? A ROC curve plots changing rates of true & false positives as a threshold is manipulated. Do you have knowledge of the true state of each point outside of the clustering? (If so, why are you using clustering instead of some method that incorporates that information?) What constitutes the threshold that can vary in your case? Moreover, what do you want a ROC curve for?

Comment: ROC curves are defined for binary classification problems, not for clustering. Maybe you can take a step back and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I do not have true information so I might not be able to get ROC curve.

Comment: @Calimo I am trying to evaluate my clustering models about how much good are they performing.

Comment: @SaqlainGardezi then you should edit your question accordingly